# pandas: Не получается разрезать массив

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

я новичок в программировании и не могу разрезать ndarray на два numpy массива.
У меня есть датафрейм. Я каждую строку датафрейма конвертировал в ndarray и потом срезами отрезал строку по 50 элементов и запихивал в  data_x, затем - следующие 22 элемента, и запихивал их в  data_y, пока не закончится строчка
вот код:

```
data_x = np.array([])
gg=0
len_x = 50
len_y = 22
data_y = np.array([])

for i in range(187):
    a = df.head(i)#df - это датафрейм, ссылка а него ниже
    m = a.tail(1)#здесь я беру строку из датафрейма
    b = np.array(m)
    for j in range(154):
        c = b[gg:len_x+gg]
        gg += len_x#счетчик чего я отрезал
        np.append(data_x,c)
        y = b[gg:len_y+gg]
        gg += len_y
        np.append(data_y,y)
        if gg >=154:
            break
    gg=0
    if (len(data_x) >=188) and (len(data_y) >=188):
        break

print(c)
```

ссылка на датафрейм - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wK2kJPAyt5EadrBA64Lx1_VggftdO87V/view?usp=sharing

но код работает не правильно: в data_y вообще ничего нет.

Comment: Вы можете уточнить как именно вы хотите разделить фрейм и что должно получиться в результате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне не совсем понятно, что вы хотите получить, но я бы вам советовал воспользоваться свойством `iloc`:

```
i, offset=0,0
while offset < len(df.columns):
    delta = 22 if i&1 else 50
    df_ = df.iloc[:, offset:delta+offset]
    offset+=delta
    i+=1
    print(df_)
```

Результат:

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  ...  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
0    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   1   1   1   4   4   5   7
1    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   2  10  12
2    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...  12  17  17  19  20  20  20
3    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
4    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
..  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..  ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
183  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   4   7  16  16  19  26  30
184  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
185  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
186  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
187  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

[188 rows x 50 columns]
     51  52  53  54  55  56  57  ...   66   67   68   69   70   71   72
0     7   7  11  16  21  22  22  ...  112  111  122  172  177  239  275
1    23  33  38  42  51  55  60  ...  189  199  218  228  244  263  279
2    24  26  37  49  54  61  76  ...  418  465  511  600  728  855  987
3     1   1   1   1   2  39  39  ...  269  312  337  380  380  394  437
4     0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...    4    5    7    7    7    8    8
..   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
183  31  31  36  39  38  40  42  ...   91   99  111  117  123  134  161
184   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
185   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
186   0   0   0   0   0   0   2  ...   22   28   29   35   35   37   40
187   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...    5    7    7    7    8    8    9

[188 rows x 22 columns]
       73    74    75    76    77    78    79  ...   116   117   118   119   120   121   122
0     283   306   352   367   431   451   493  ...  6408  6679  7155  7878  8309  8906  9349
1     306   339   366   382   393   406   417  ...   954   954   956   967   969   976  1000
2    1187  1267  1328  1455  1507  1616  1703  ...  6973  7111  7355  7420  7761  7913  7926
3     441   471   510   539   559   573   597  ...   771   762   775   768   774   783   775
4       8    10    14    16    17    19    19  ...    49    48    51    52    53    60    61
..    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
183   195   221   241   256   265   267   271  ...   378   383   393   400   404   429   424
184     0     0     4     4     4     4     4  ...     6     6     6     6     6     6     6
185     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  ...   122   129   133   169   186   200   213
186    40    40    39    39    40    40    40  ...   689   757   768   778   841   890   920
187     9     9     9    10    11    11    11  ...    43    44    46    47    49    52    51

[188 rows x 50 columns]
       123    124    125    126    127    128    129  ...    138    139    140    141    142    143    144
0    10245  10662  11374  11959  12692  13384  13783  ...  20627  20958  21765  22712  22979  23927  24264
1     1001   1004   1017   1029   1069   1077   1130  ...   1269   1272   1308   1359   1420   1448   1486
2     8287   8425   8568   8801   9111   9113   9169  ...  10436  10397  10424  10562  10699  10826  10887
3      779    785    785    782    776    776    767  ...    853    858    866    858    877    878    878
4       63     71     71     71     71     76     82  ...     92     94     97    113    121    130    141
..     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...  ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
183    433    424    423    435    444    457    446  ...    483    487    482    498    490    495    497
184      6      9      9      9      9      9      9  ...      9      9      9      9      9      9      9
185    216    225    237    256    257    286    286  ...    490    506    532    572    603    635    720
186    938    928    931    927   1078   1085   1078  ...   1110   1217   1220   1226   1225   1330   1385
187     56     56     57     57    135    152    150  ...    282    289    323    324    338    352    362

[188 rows x 22 columns]
       145    146    147    148    149    150    151    152    153    154    155
0    24787  25582  26602  26990  28176  28205  29067  29460  29233  29854  30511
1     1523   1632   1710   1742   1822   1838   1926   2019   2015   2093   2166
2    10946  11110  11240  11475  11488  11536  11649  11805  11943  12091  12429
3      860    877    861    866    864    873    878    870    867    863    869
4      140    144    150    156    169    176    176    186    189    193    201
..     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
183    504    512    517    567    605    680    785    840   1010   1171   1348
184      9      9      9      9      9      9      9      9     10     10     10
185    729    845    896    919    936    945    947    969    973   1007   1041
186   1360   1390   1437   1449   1432   1457   1471   1469   1439   1512   1501
187    389    396    398    409    472    488    482    497    514    540    544

[188 rows x 11 columns]
```

**UPDATE**

В общем, мне до сих пор не совсем ясна задача, но если автор вопроса хочет раскидать срезы по 50 и по 22 с разные массивы соответственно, то можно сделать так:

```
i, offset=0,0
res22 = pd.DataFrame({0 : []})
res50 = pd.DataFrame({0 : []})
while offset < len(df.columns):
    delta = 22 if (i&1) else 50
    if i&1:
        res22 = pd.concat((res22, df.iloc[:, offset:delta+offset]), axis=1)
    else:
        res50 = pd.concat((res50, df.iloc[:, offset:delta+offset]), axis=1)    
    offset+=delta
    i+=1
# выше мы получили 2 датафрейма res22 и res50 с данными из срезов по 50 и 22 колонки соответственно. 
# Если нужно превратить их в массивы numpy, то это можно сделать так:
narr22 = res22.drop(columns=[0]).to_numpy()
narr50 = res50.drop(columns=[0]).to_numpy()
```

Результат (пример):

```
narr22
array([[    7,     7,    11, ..., 22979, 23927, 24264],
       [   23,    33,    38, ...,  1420,  1448,  1486],
       [   24,    26,    37, ..., 10699, 10826, 10887],
       ...,
       [    0,     0,     0, ...,   603,   635,   720],
       [    0,     0,     0, ...,  1225,  1330,  1385],
       [    0,     0,     0, ...,   338,   352,   362]], dtype=int64)

narr50:
array([[    0,     0,     0, ..., 29233, 29854, 30511],
       [    0,     0,     0, ...,  2015,  2093,  2166],
       [    0,     0,     0, ..., 11943, 12091, 12429],
       ...,
       [    0,     0,     0, ...,   973,  1007,  1041],
       [    0,     0,     0, ...,  1439,  1512,  1501],
       [    0,     0,     0, ...,   514,   540,   544]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Это то что я хотел, но только это надо было в 2 массива.

Comment: в два массива какой размерности?

Comment: Вы я как понимаю сделали один массив и там подмассивы по 50  и 22 колонок, а я бы хотел 2 массива в первом массиве были подмассивы по 50 колонок а во втором массиве были подмассивы по 22 колонки.А размерность я не совсем понял как ответить